# C# and DataGridView: Filtering does not work

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, .net

I have a serious problem regarding my `DataGridView` and filtering. I know there a number of topics out there regarding this and I read most of them without finding any solution to my problem

I have a DataGridView with a object DataSource (BindingSource).
I have a Textbox to enter search expressions to be filtered.
Problem is: Nothing happens at all.

- BindingSource is set (currentSignals as DataSource prop of DataGridView)
- Column Name / Property Name is "Name", so that is what I want to use as filter source

from object source file:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
}
```

Search Expression goes like this

```
var searchString = (sender as TextBox).Text;
var filterExpression = "Name LIKE '%" + searchString + "%'";
_currentSignals.Filter = filterExpression;
```

So this goes without exception but actually nothing happens in my DGV. Nothing at all. What am I doing wrong? Did I miss a prop (Allow filtering?) or something like that?
May this be related to the fact that the BindingSource elements (user-defined class) are missing an interface?

Comment: It may help to see more of the code, are you refreshing the DataGridView?

Comment: Yes, but without breaking the binding. What would you like to see?

Comment: You should  end editing  with .EndEdit and then Refresh the datagrid.